# How to batch edit photos with digiKam and have a preview?

Tags: photo-editing, batch, digikam

I am not a professional photographer so I do not know the proper terms for many things, I apology myself for this. I will pose my question with an example.

I have a set of pictures in [digiKam](https://www.digikam.org/):

[image]

They were all taken at the same place and time, so they all look very similar. Now I want to apply some color-brightness-etc. corrections to these photos, so I right click one and click `open`, the `Image editor` opens and I can do whatever I want. For example this:

[image]

Now I want to apply the exact same process I made within the `Image editor` to all the pictures. I have found that using the `Batch queue manager` this can be done:

[image]

In this case, however, there is not any preview of what each operation is going to do, so I have to proceed blinded. Not an option for me.

Of course one possibility is to open the `Batch queue manager` and the `Image editor` simultaneously and to *manually replicate each operation I perform for one picture in the `Image editor` into the `Batch queue manager`*.

[image]

This is better than manually editing each picture, but is still a bit cumbersome and does not look like the way to go.

I have tried to copy the filters in the `Used filters` tabe (see second screenshot) but it is not allowed.

So, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: WHat about copy settings and then paste them on each image?

Comment: How can I do that? I have tried to copy the settings from the `Filters used` tab but it is not allowed.

Comment: `Image » Metadata » Export EXIF`, click on next image,  `Image » Metadata » Import EXIF` may do the work

Comment: I cannot find that, I am using digiKam version 7.2.0. I can go to `Image → Metadata → EXIF` but cannot export/import that.